# Trying count distinct strings, whats going wrong

Tags: c++

whats wrong in this approach

```
#include<algorithm>
#include<iomanip>
#include<ios>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>

using std::cin;using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::setprecision;
using std::string;
using std::streamsize;
using std::sort;
using std::vector;

int main(){

    string zz;
    typedef vector<string> vs;

    vs input,distinct;vector<int> count;
    cout<<"Enter the words";
    while(cin>>zz){
        input.push_back(zz);
    }

    if(input.size()==0){
        cout<<"Enter atleast a single    word";
        return 1;
    }

    int i=0,j=0;
    sort(input.begin(),input.end());
    while(i!=input.size()){
        int count2=0;
        for(j=i;j<input.size();j++)
        {
            if(input[j]==input[j+1])
            {
                count2++;
            }else{ 
                break;
            }
        }
        distinct.push_back(input[i]);
        count.push_back(count2);
        i+=count2;continue;
        i++;
    }

    for(i=0;i<distinct.size();i++)
    {
        cout<<distinct[i]<<"\t           time"<<count[i]<<"\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

i am using ubuntu 12.10 `gcc4.7`

The task it two count distinct number of given inputs and display it.
the program ask for input and doesnt stop taking input even after the end of file i.e ctrl+d

Comment: And where is the condition to stop taking input when EOF?

Comment: #include<algorithm>
#include<iomanip>
#include<ios>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
these are the includes .
i was asking from mobile so it wasnt there in the above code

Comment: the condition of testing end of file is from while(cin>>zz) 
go test it on your pc

Comment: Program. (You did that.) Input. Observed behaviour. Expected behaviour.

Comment: And I swear, if I see one more `typedef` for a vector of strings, I'll go on a rampage. :-D

Comment: @DevSolar rampage away - I'm more amused by trying to make everything two letters. Why not go for one?

Comment: @doctorlove: Or the attempt to optimize by leaving out as many whitespaces as possible. Or the rather inconsistent use of ANSI vs. "egyptian" / Java brackets... Ah, gone the days where people took pride in form, not just function. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not your read loop. It gets stuck in an infinite loop in

```
while(i!=input.size()){
```

Think carefully about your end condition, and the lines that change `i`:

```
    i+=count2;continue;
    i++;
```

Will `i++` ever be executed? Will `i` ever *exactly* equal `input.size()`? If there *are* repeated words? If there are *not*?

.

.

.

Ok, thought about it? I replaced that loop with this. The comments should explain:

```
while(i < input.size())
{
    // Store current string
    distinct.push_back(input[i]);

    // Skip same strings
    int j = i;
    while ( j < input.size() // Don't go too far
            && input[i] == input[j] ) // And only while duplicates
        ++j;

    // Store a count of how many we skipped
    count.push_back(j-i);

    // Move to the next *non-identical* string
    i=j;
}
```

Of course, there are much nicer ways to do this using Standard Library algorithms, but I assume this is a simple educational exercise.

Note also that the way round I wrote that `&&` matters! The other way round and you try to compare the last string to something off the end.

Comment: what if i dont want to sort the given data and do the given task